# Table of planar connected graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics

For the other day I need to use the table of planar connected graph with few vertex. In the [wolfram's mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlanarGraph.html) , they listed only the graph with $4$ vertex.

Does anyone knows *webpages* or *pdf* on the web which carries the table of planar connected graph with up to $10$ edges?

Comment: Do you want to allow multiple edges, or only get the simple graphs?

Comment: In the question the table in mathworld is simple ones, but the graphs I want to know is the planar graph that allows multiple edges, and they are visually described.

Answer (score 12):

A lot depends on what the question means, in particular are the graphs simple, and is equivalence defined by embedding-preserving isomorphism or all graph isomorphisms.

For simple graphs up to general isomorphism, see [my page](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html) for files up to 11 vertices.

For simple graphs up to embedding-preserving isomorphism, use [plantri](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/plantri/) to make them.  The command for $n$ vertices is "plantri -pc1m1 $n$", or "plantri -opc1m1 $n$" if mirror-image doesn't count as isomorphism. (At first, add "-u" to just count rather than output.) Tables up to 14 vertices are in [this paper](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/plantri-full.pdf), Table 22.

Comment: What I want to know is the planar graph that allows multiple edges up to embedding-preserving isomorphism, and visually illustrated. Does anybody know the table that illustrate these graphs?

Comment: @this_is_an_apple If you allow multiple edges there is an infinite number of graphs even for just 2 vertices, since you can have any number of edges between them (and still be planar).

Comment: @this_is_an_apple such illustrated tables are included in the atlas by Jackson and Visentin I referenced above. Since you are considering planar graphs with multiple edges up to embedding-preserving isomorphism, it sounds like the objects you are interested in are precisely what are known as "planar maps".

Comment: >there is an infinite number of graphs $~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$                      To avoid the situation, I wrote "10 edges" in the question above.

Answer (score 4):

You can generate all connected graphs with no more than 10 edges quickly using Brendan McKay's NAUTY program availible at http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/ using (example for 11 vertices, which is maximum):

> geng -c 11 0:10

and filter then using "planarg" from the same package. That is if you really mean "up to 10 edges" (not vertices). I've posted a list of all such 3386 such graphs at http://pastebin.com/P5vrZH7X (obtained in the way just described, in graph6 format).

If it is the planar connected graphs with up to 10 *vertices* you want you may find them at House of Graphs: http://hog.grinvin.org/Planar

Comment: http://hog.grinvin.org/Planar#planar is exactly the page that I want to know.   It costs some time to translate code into graph, but I would try it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite an answer, but two possible sources:

(1) [A003094](https://oeis.org/A003094) lists the number of unlabeled connected planar simple graphs with $n$ nodes:
$$1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 20, 99, 646, 5974, 71885, 1052805, 17449299, 313372298\;.$$

(2) Read, Ronald C., and Robin J. Wilson. *An atlas of graphs*. Clarendon Press, 1998.
I can't access more than the table of contents of this book at the moment:

---

[image: ReadWilsonCh5]

---

Answer (score 2):

In `Sage`, see `www.sagemath.org`, you find the algorithm

G. Brinkmann and B.D. McKay, *Fast generation of planar graphs*, MATCH-Communications in Mathematical and in Computer Chemistry, 58(2):323-357, 2007.

implemented, for which the optional package `plantri` needs to be installed. From the documentation:

```
    An iterator over connected planar graphs using the plantri generator.

    This uses the plantri generator (see [plantri]_) which is available
    through the optional package plantri.

    .. NOTE::

        The non-3-connected graphs will be returned several times, with all
        its possible embeddings.
```

Here are a few tests:

```
sage: %time len(list(graphs.planar_graphs(4)))
CPU times: user 3.23 ms, sys: 7.93 ms, total: 11.2 ms
Wall time: 21.6 ms
6

sage: %time len(list(graphs.planar_graphs(5)))
CPU times: user 11.9 ms, sys: 8.35 ms, total: 20.3 ms
Wall time: 31.9 ms
25

sage: %time len(list(graphs.planar_graphs(6)))
CPU times: user 72.5 ms, sys: 11.7 ms, total: 84.2 ms
Wall time: 96.3 ms
179

sage: %time len(list(graphs.planar_graphs(7)))
CPU times: user 920 ms, sys: 67.3 ms, total: 988 ms
Wall time: 1 s
2014

sage: %time len(list(graphs.planar_graphs(8)))
CPU times: user 19.6 s, sys: 914 ms, total: 20.5 s
Wall time: 20.6 s
31178
```

Comment: Okay, this is neither a `website` nor a `pdf`. But you can use the website `cloud.sagemath.com` to generate the data...

Comment: Interestingly, plantri only needs 0.02 seconds to generate the 31178 graphs with 8 vertices.  The rest must be overhead from sage to read them and make a list of them.

Comment: That is right, I remember reading (can't find it back right now) that almost all the time is used to create Sage graphs out of the data.

Comment: That's a nice algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Close to what you are looking for, there is

- *An Atlas of the Smaller Maps in Orientable and Nonorientable Surfaces* by David Jackson and Terry I. Visentin. ([CRC press](https://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781584882077)) ([Google books](https://books.google.fr/books?id=aNgyxbl4XkEC&lpg=PA11&ots=vHB4fSC-Zm&dq=%22An%20Atlas%20of%20the%20Smaller%20Maps%20in%20Orientable%20and%20Nonorientable%20Surfaces%22&pg=PA290#v=onepage&q=%22An%20Atlas%20of%20the%20Smaller%20Maps%20in%20Orientable%20and%20Nonorientable%20Surfaces%22&f=false))

This book includes tables of all of the [topological maps](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+map) of genus 0 with up to five edges, ordered by number of vertices (it includes many other tables as well).  Note that a topological map of genus 0 can be seen as a connected planar graph with a bit of extra structure (a cyclic ordering of half-edges around each vertex).